# Creating vectors from integer inputs and then duplicating the elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

you're going to hate me for asking such a simple question but I don't understand why this code won't work!

```
test = input('Please enter an integer:')
vec = []'
B = int2str(test)
for i = 1:length(test)
   vec = [vec;B(i)]
   end
C = kron(vec,ones(100,1))
```

So basically what it's supposed to do is take in an integer from a user such as 101 then convert it into a column vector [1,0,1]' and then duplicate each element by 3 times so you get [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]' but instead I am getting [49,49,49,48,48,48,47,47,47]' which I understand are the ascii values but I don't get why it's doing this to me. I had to convert the user input into a string otherwise it woundn't convert it into a column vector at all but by doing so it messes with the rest of the code...any help will be appreciated - thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `vec` is of type `char`, not numeric. Applying a numeric operation (such as `kron`) to a `char` *automatically converts the characters to their [ASCII codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)*. That's why you get `49` for `'1'` etc.

You need to convert back from ASCII code to the number it represents. To do that, since all decimal digits have correlative ASCII codes, you can just subtract the ASCII code of `'0'`, which is 48:

```
vec = vec-48;
```

Or, more commonly (exploiting again the fact that subtracting a `char` means subtracting its ASCII code):

```
vec = vec-'0';
```

Comment: Also the loop must go to length(B) instead of length(test)

Comment: @luis Mendo Thanks a lot! That makes a lot of sense, I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

This also can help you with the problem,

```
t = input('Please enter an integer:');
t = num2str(t);
t = repmat(t,3,1);
t = t(:)';
```